# Should I reset a table index / optimize after deletion of many rows?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, sql-delete

I have a table with 1,000,000 records and I'm running a statement that's deleting ~700k rows. The auto-increment-index is of course still at 1,000,001. The highest primary key afterwards for example 40,000.

After such a huge deletion of rows should I manually set the index back to 40,001 or optimize the table in any way? Or doesn't MySQL care for this huge gap when inserting new rows and using the index in select statements afterwards (in terms of speed)?

Comment: Re-using ID numbers is never a good idea unless you're really, really low on available IDs.

Comment: @Matti: Even then, it's more likely better to use a different data type for the ID column, such as bigint (unsigned of course) to prevent collisions with prior deleted keys...

Comment: Hmm .. I guess you are right, re-using primary keys seems to be a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html) says:

> OPTIMIZE TABLE should be used if you
>   have deleted a large part of a table
>   or if you have made many changes to a
>   table with variable-length rows

But don't reset the primary key, it can mess things up. The INT datatype (presumably) has a lot of room to grow from 1M.

In terms of query speed, it doesn't matter whether the index value is at 1 000 000 or at 1 000 000 000.

Answer (score 1):

Using OPTIMIZE TABLE afterwards helps MySQL determine how best/fastest to peform queries, e.g. use index or just table scan? It uses what are called Statistics to do so, and so calling OPTIMIZE TABLE is basically giving it a hint that you've made a significant change.